# Cannot install Android Studio under Windows 8 64bit

Tags: android, android-studio

I get a very bizarre error trying to install Android Studio under Windows 8.
Does anybody know where it comes from or what I can do about it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Pops up about 3 seconds after I start the installation.]

Comment: Wild guess: If setup crashed during detection of Java, maybe you have no Java installed?

Comment: I use the JDK 1.7.0_25 and have JAVA_HOME, JAVA_JDK and PATH set in the env. variables. I do use this for projects with other IDEs at this very moment.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I haven't.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky So here (below) is the solution which worked for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why, but installing "Java for Chrome" (.exe) made everything work.
This is awkward as I did have Java (same version 1.7.u25) installed and used before with all the environment variables set.

Comment: For me the ultimate solution was to delete all Javasoft entries from my Registry..